# How to call SQL Server Express command line using c# to run a .sql file

Tags: c#, setup-project, sql-server-2008-express

I have to make a setup for window application so I need to create a database on client machine. So I decided that I will create it using a `.sql` file which I will add in my resource file. As there is a option to execute that file on first run of my program that will create my database.

But as one of my friend suggested, that `.sql` file should be executed from command line of SQL Server Express.

I have searched a lot for how to execute a `.sql` file from c# code in SQL Server 2008 Express command line.

I already read these questions

- [How can I execute a .sql from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449646/how-can-i-execute-a-sql-from-c)

Code:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath),  "HotelReservationScript.sql"));                
StreamReader fileRead = file.OpenText();

string script = fileRead.ReadToEnd();

fileRead.Close();
string strConn = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MasterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConn);
con.Open();

ExecuteScript(con, script);

protected virtual void ExecuteScript(SqlConnection connection, string script)
{
    string[] commandTextArray = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(script, "\r\n[\t ]*GO");

    SqlCommand _cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Empty, connection);

    foreach (string commandText in commandTextArray)
    {
        if (commandText.Trim() == string.Empty) 
            continue;

        if ((commandText.Length >= 3) && (commandText.Substring(0, 3).ToUpper() == "USE"))
        {
            throw new Exception("Create script contains USE statement. Please provide non database specific create scripts!");
        }

        _cmd.CommandText = commandText;
        _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Could not find file 'C:\Users\Kiran\Desktop\rahhul\Bookster_28\HotelReservationSystem\HotelReservationSystem\bin\Debug\HotelReservationScript.sql'

**EDITED :**

I also tried this but I get the same error

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().ToString()), "HotelReservationScript.sql"));
```

Comment: Why can't you do it the way it is done in the link you provided?

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://forums.learnsqlserver.com/sqlservertopic53.aspx

Comment: take another look at your error message.  The file doesn't exist, or can't be found.  If you're sure it exists, check that your program has permissions to find it in that folder.  This is not a c# or sql issue

Comment: @deltree error solved as i have to set the properties of that .sql file copy every timr in property window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs().ToString()), "HotelReservationScript.sql"));
```

**error solved as i have to set the properties of that .sql file copy every timr in property window.**